# Consuming Server Sent Events(SSE) without losing data using scala and Akka

Tags: scala, playframework, akka, reactive-programming, akka-stream

I want to consume SSE events without losing any data when the rate of production is > rate of consumption. Since SSE supports backpressure Akka should be able to do it. I tried a few different ways but the extra messages are being dropped.

```
@Singleton
class SseConsumer @Inject()()(implicit ec: ExecutionContext) {

  implicit val system = ActorSystem()

  val send: HttpRequest => Future[HttpResponse] = foo

  def foo(x: HttpRequest) = {
    try {
      val authHeader = Authorization(BasicHttpCredentials("user", "pass"))
      val newHeaders = x.withHeaders(authHeader)
      Http().singleRequest(newHeaders)
    } catch {
      case e: Exception => {
        println("Exceptio12n", e.printStackTrace())
        throw e
      }
    }
  }


  val eventSource2: Source[ServerSentEvent, NotUsed] =
    EventSource(
      uri = Uri("https://xyz/a/events/user"),
      send,
      initialLastEventId = Some("2"),
      retryDelay = 1.second
    )


  def orderStatusEventStable() = {
    val events: Future[immutable.Seq[ServerSentEvent]] =
      eventSource2
        .throttle(elements = 1, per = 3000.milliseconds, maximumBurst = 1, ThrottleMode.Shaping)
        .take(5)
        .runWith(Sink.seq)
    events.map(_.foreach(x => {
      // TODO: push to sqs
      println("456")
      println(x.data)
    }))
  }


  Future {
    blocking {
      while (true) {
        try {
          Await.result(orderStatusEventStable() recover {
            case e: Exception => {
              println("exception", e)
              throw e
            }
          }, Duration.Inf)
        } catch {
          case e: Exception => {
            println("Exception", e.printStackTrace())
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This code works but with the following problems:

1. Due to `.take(5)` when rate of consumption < rate of production, I am dropping events.
2. Also I want to process each message as it comes, and don't want to wait until 5 messages have reached. How can I do that ?
3. I have to write the consumer in a while loop. This does not seem event based, rather looks like polling (very similar to calling GET with pagination and limit of 5)
4. I am not sure about throttling, tried reading the docs but its very confusing. If I don't want to lose any events, is throttling the right approach? I am expecting a rate of 5000 req / sec in peak hours and 10 req/sec otherwise. When the production rate is high I would I ideally want to apply backpressure. Is throttling the correct approach for that ? According to docs it seems correct as it says `Backpressures when downstream backpressures or the incoming rate is higher than the speed limit`

Answer (score 0):

In order for Akka Stream back pressuring to work, you have to use only one source instead of recreating a kind of polling with a new source each time.

Forget about your loop and your `def orderStatusEventStable`.

Only do something like this (once):

```
eventSource2
  .operator(event => /* do something */ )
  .otherOperatorMaybe()
  ...
  .runWith(Sink.foreach(println))
```

With `operator` and `otherOperatorMaybe` being operations on Akka Stream depending on what you want to achieve (like `throttle` and `take` in your original code).

List of operators: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/index.html

*Akka Stream is powerful but you need to take some time to learn about it*